# Pointing main domain to another server while keeping subdomains in same place

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, github

I have a domain I want to point to my github pages site. However, I want to keep the subdomain `old.mysite.com` pointing at the current server (as this is an archive of my old php blog, which github pages can't host).

How would I go about doing this (Ideally using the tools available in cPanel)?

Comment: Remember, any links that used to point to your old blog will become dead (or at least show up as 404s on the new GitHub blog).

Comment: If this is an issue, GitHub does not have a way of redirecting from the server side, but you can set up HTTP redirects using some manual work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the following DNS records:

```
www.mysite.com  CNAME  youruser.github.io
old.mysite.com  A      ip.address.of.your.server
```

Given that you can't have a CNAME on the bare domain (mysite.com) you should point it to your server and make it a redirect to www.mysite.com on the http level. GitHub can also take care of the redirect for you, but I would avoid doing that as you will need to keep the A record up-to-date yourself (ALIAS records are rare). See the [GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#setting-up-dns)

Comment: perfect - thanks. For anyone who is using cPanel the ability to set this is found under 'Advanced DNS zone editor'