# How to configure DNS to point main domain at Firebase hosting, but not subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system

I currently have a website hosting on CPanel which consists of subdomain.example.com and example.com. I'd like to keep the subdomain hosted where it is, but move the main domain to be hosted with Firebase. I'm struggling to work out the required DNS changes to make this work.

If it is relevant, the domain was purchased from 123-reg and points to custom nameservers on my CPanel server.

I read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/579263), but I've also read that Firebase no longer allows CNAME records and has to be A records.

Would it work to have an A record pointing to the IP addresses supplied by Firebase and a CNAME record for the subdomain pointing to the server where it is currently hosted?

Comment: The apex `example.com` cannot contain an NS record (which is obviously required) and a CNAME record. You thus must use an A record to point to the IP address of the Firebase web server, as stated in the answer of Massimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two A records:

- domain.com -> Public IP address of your first server
- sub.domain.com - Public IP address of your second server